# Optimal strategy of modified Mastermind game

Tags: co.combinatorics, it.information-theory, permutations, game-theory

The following game is a modified version of the popular game Mastermind described [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=185) in which you are only given information about the total correct guesses you have made, and nothing about how many correct digits in wrong place you have. The game goes as follows

Player one starts the game by secretly selecting a sequence of the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ without duplicates. We'll call this sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$.

Player two then at every turn chooses a sequence of numbers $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$, upon which Player 1 will inform them *solely* of the number of values $1\leq j\leq n$ such that $a_j=b_j$. Player 2's goal is to guess the correct sequence in the minimum number of possible turns.

**Question**: What is the smallest number of turns that it can take Player 2 to determine the sequence of Player 1's secret configuration?

---

Clearly Player 2 can just guess each individual number's placement one at a time, which would lead us to the scale of $O(n^2)$ guesses required, however it seems as if there is a better strategy that can take advantage of the knowledge of incorrect as well as correct placements.

Comment: You can do $n+1$ guesses by $1,2,...,n$, then $2,3,...,n,1$, and so on, and then you will know all values.

Comment: Wait, does he get the number of matches or the indices?

Comment: If he gets the number then see, for example, the paper [Playing Mastermind with Many Colors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0773) which shows an upper bound of $O(n\log\log n)$, and as far as I know it's the best known

Comment: @CommandMaster Player 2 knows the *number* of matches, not the indices